# jquery dropdown only when current button is hovered

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and am not sure how to solve this jQuery dropdown problem I am having.

When you hover over one of the links, the dropdown menu works fine, however I have added a second dropdown to the navigation, and now when you hover one of the links, both the dropdowns are revealed. I only want the current dropdown menu to be revealed.

Here is my code, and a link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K2Zzh/1/...

```
$('.dropdown ul').hide();   
$('.dropdown').hover(function(){
    $('.dropdown ul').stop().slideDown(500);
    },function(){
    $('.dropdown ul').stop().slideUp(200);
});
```

I know why it is doing what it is doing, and I know I should be using a `this` somewhere but I am not sure where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to only target the relevant list, similar to this:

```
var $dropdown;

$('.dropdown ul').hide();
$('.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $dropdown = $(this).find('ul');
    $dropdown.stop().slideDown(500);
}, function() {
    $dropdown.stop().slideUp(200);
});​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K2Zzh/4/)

The only reason why I'm using a variable above is so you don't have to traverse twice for the same dropdown, which is a good habit to get into.

You can off course do this too:

```
$('.dropdown ul').hide();
$('.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').stop().slideDown(500);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('ul').stop().slideUp(200);
});​
```

Also, the reason I used [**find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [**children()**](http://api.jquery.com/children/) is because `children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree while `find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements.

In your particular case `childrend()` seems absolutly fine though as you are only 1 level down.

**Edit**
For completeness sake, if you want to use [**slideToggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) within a single hover function you can do as seen in another answer:

```
$('.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideToggle(500);
}
```

Note though that when using this option you might need to include `true, true` in your [**stop()**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) call to prevent the sliding menu from `lagging` and possibly becoming reversed.

> - **clearQueueA** Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as
>     well. Defaults to false.
> - **jumpToEndA** Boolean indicating whether to
>     complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to false.

Comment: This version does seem a lot more stable so will mark this is the right answer. Thanks for your effort in this

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$(selector, context)` or `find` method.

```
$('.dropdown ul').hide();    
$('.dropdown').hover(function(){
    $('ul', this).stop().slideToggle(500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JKG5N/

Comment: @Adam: This way seems to have broken the slide functionality. Hover over `home` then `treatments`, then back to `home` and back to `treatments`. Your slider is now moving in opposite directions, showing the `treatment` menu when hovering over `home` instead. To fix this, please use `stop(true, true)` instead of just `stop()`.

Comment: Yes you are right, however I think this is a jsfiddle issue. I have integrated the above code in my page, and it seems to work fine. I cannot recreate the problem on my own page

Comment: @Adam: In that case this answer looks very good. +1 to `undefined` for nice short-hand, though `stop(true, true)` **may** have to be added.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a context to your dropdown hover functions. The event handlers happen in the context of the element being hovered over, so if you say `$('ul', this).stop().slideDown(500)` and `$('ul', this).stop().slideUp(200)` it should work.

Modified jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zbGH/1/

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your code like below :

```
$('.dropdown ul').hide();    

$('.dropdown').hover(function(){
      $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown(500);
    },function(){
      $(this).children('ul').stop().slideUp(200);
});
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K2Zzh/3/)**